# Converting if into ternary operator in C#

Tags: c#, .net

how can I convert this simple if statement into :? (ternary) operator in C#?

```
case "amount": { if(!Decimal.TryParse( fvm.Value,out a)) a=Decimal.MinValue; break; }
```

Comment: the question should be: **why**? Seems pretty simple and easy to understand IMHO. I´d just put everything on new lines though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either assign the value of `a` back to itself on success, or use a separate temporary variable (I'd prefer the latter):

```cs
case: "amount":
    a = decimal.TryParse(fvm.Value, out var tmp) ? tmp : decimal.MinValue;
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Decimal.TryParse( fvm.Value,out var tmp) ? tmp : Decimal.MinValue;
break;
```

I would personally prefer to create an helper method

```
public static decimal? ParseDecimal(string str) => Decimal.TryParse(str, out var tmp) ? (decimal?)tmp : null;
```

since that would let you use the null-coalescing operator:

```
a = ParceDecimal(fvm.Value) ?? decimal.MinValue
```